# Find all contacts in outlook with Ruby

Tags: ruby, outlook, contacts

I'm using tidesdk to make a desktop app , connected with MS Outlook.
App is working well but...

When I get contacts from outlook I use this.

```
def getContacts()

        #ouverture de l'application outlook
        begin
            application = WIN32OLE.new('Outlook.Application')
        rescue Exception=>e
            alert("An error occurred while opening outlook, no contacts will be loaded");
            return false
        end

        mapi = application.GetNameSpace('MAPI')

        contacts = mapi.GetDefaultFolder(10).Items
        contacts.each do |contact|

            begin
                puts contact.FullName
                puts contact.Email1Address
                puts contact.BusinessTelephoneNumber
                addContactApp(contact.FullName, contact.Email1Address)
            rescue Exception=>e
                alert("An error occurred while loading contacts");
            end
        end
    end
```

That's working too... but I have more than one folder in my contact list, and i'd like to get ALL contacts from ALL folders in MS Outlook. Is it possible to get all contacts folders ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with the `Namespace.Folders` collection and recursively process each folder and its subfolders (`MAPIFolder.Folders`) checking the `MAPIFolder.DefaultItemType` property.

Answer (score 1):

This is not at all what I had in mind: you are only processing the items in the subfolders of the default Contacts folder. If you have a folder with contacts on the same level as the Inbox or the Contacts folder itself, it will not be processed - you need to start with Namespace.Folders and check the DefaultItemType property to make sure you only process contacts folders. Secondly, you are assuming you only have contacts. If you have a distribution list, your code will raise an error since DistListItem object does not support FullName/Email1Address/etc. properties. Check if the Class property (exposed by all OOM objects) equals 40 (OlObjectClass.olContact).

Comment: I gonna try to make your tips, it will be better to check all folders, wasn't in my mind !! Thx !

Answer (score 0):

Thx for your answer !! I've tried this and it's working fine !

```
mapi = application.GetNameSpace('MAPI')
        contacts_all_folders = mapi.GetDefaultFolder(10).Folders
        contacts_all_folders.each do |folder|           
            var myfolder = mapi.GetDefaultFolder(10).Folders(folder.Name).Items
            myfolder.each do |contact|
                begin
                    puts contact.FullName
                    puts contact.Email1Address
                    puts contact.BusinessTelephoneNumber
                    addContactApp(contact.FullName, contact.Email1Address)
                rescue Exception=>e
                    alert("An error occurred while loading contacts "+e);
                end
            end
        end
```